# How can i replace double quotes with escape character in java?

Tags: java, string

I have such text :

```
"fullName":"\"Some full name\"" .
```

How could i replace `""` with `"` ? I tried like this :

```
text.replace("\"\"","\"");
```

But i got `"fullName":"\"Some full name\"`. As you can see only second `""` have been replaced by `"`.

Comment: Because there is stuff between the other quotes? Your text replacement doesn't account for the text between the quotes

Comment: There is a difference between a string that contains `"fullName":"\"Some full name\""` and one that contains `"fullName":""Some full name""`. Make sure to account for the slashes.

Comment: it looks like you are dealing with json data.  maybe it would be better to use a json parser?

Comment: @jtahlborn can it be done by Gson?

Comment: sure.  and jackson and json.org and simplejson and any number of other java json libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first replace `\"` with `"` and then replace `""` with `"`.

You can do it by chaining a few [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) calls:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\\"","\"").replaceAll("\"\"", "\"");
System.out.println(text);
```

which will produce

```
"fullName":"Some full name"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by matching `\""` or `"\"`:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\\"\"|\"\\\\\"", "\"");
```

This uses an *alternation* (via `|`). The ugliness of all those back slashes is due to both java *and* the regex requiring escaping of backslashes (in java, `"\\"` is a literal backslash, so `"\\\\"` is a literal backslash in a regex).

---

Some test code:

```
String str = "\"fullName\":\"\\\"Some full name\\\"\"";
System.out.println(str); // just to make sure
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\\\\\"\"|\"\\\\\"", "\""));
```

Output:

```
"fullName":"\"Some full name\""
"fullName":"Some full name"
```